# Extract Hash values using Hash#dig

Tags: ruby, hash, dig, ruby-2.3

```
h = {
  users: {
    u_548912: {
      name: "John",
      age: 30
    },
    u_598715: {
      name: "Doe",
      age: 30
    }
  }
}
```

Given a hash like above, say I want to get user *John*, I can do

```
h[:users].values.first[:name]    # => "John"
```

In Ruby 2.3 use `Hash#dig` can do the same thing:

```
h.dig(:users, :u_548912, :name)  # => "John"
```

But given that the `u_548912` is just a random number(no way to know it before hand), is there a way to get the information still using `Hash#dig`?

Comment: Is there a way to calculate this number?

Comment: you pretty much have to know the keys beforehand when using `Hash#dig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, of course, pass an expression as an argument to `#dig`:

```
h.dig(:users, h.dig(:users)&.keys&.first, :name)
#=> John
```

Extract the key if you want more legibility, at the cost of lines of code:

```
first_user_id = h.dig(:users)&.keys&.first
h.dig(:users, first_user_id, :name)
#=> John
```

Another option would be to chain your `#dig` method calls. This is shorter, but a bit less legible.

```
h.dig(:users)&.values&.dig(0, :name)
#=> John
```

I'm afraid there is no "neater" way of doing this while still having safe navigation.

Comment: why not just `h[:users].values.first[:name]`

Comment: If `h[:users]` does not respond to `#values`, or `h[:users].values` does not respond to `#first`, or `h[:users].values.first` does not respond to `#[]`, your application blows up. You get the idea. :-) Both `#dig` and the safe navigation (lonely) operator were implemented in 2.3 to avoid this.

Comment: legit, but ugly af :)